# Return Entire field from GetBestFragment in FastVectorHighlighter

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, highlighter.net, fast-vector-highlighter

In Highlighter.Net, we can use NullFragmenter to return the entire field content. Is there any way we can do this in FastVectorHighlighter.Net?

Answer (score 2):

If you use **SimpleFragListBuilder**-fragmenter for **FastVectorHighlighter** then need to modify a public static properties of fragmenter to manage fragment size:

```
var fieldContent = "some data";

SimpleFragListBuilder.MARGIN = fieldContent.Length;
SimpleFragListBuilder.MIN_FRAG_CHAR_SIZE = SimpleFragListBuilder.MARGIN*3;

var result = highlighter.GetBestFragment(.., fragCharSize: SimpleFragListBuilder.MIN_FRAG_CHAR_SIZE);
```

(see source for details - 'Lucene.Net  3.0.3 SimpleFragListBuilder.cs' [[http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dd/d38/_simple_frag_list_builder_8cs_source.html]](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dd/d38/_simple_frag_list_builder_8cs_source.html))

Comment: I would set SimpleFragListBuilder.MIN_FRAG_CHAR_SIZE = 0 just to not have to worry about it. And sending fragCharSize: desiredMaximumLength.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it an option to just use `document.Get("field_name")` and return the entire field content in such a way? You probably have you document somewhere in the context anyway (as you need doc id to `GetBestFragment()`), so why not just use it?

Comment: You may wrap this content with your formatter html (I know, it's conceptually ugly, but sometimes such things are inevitable).

Comment: The problem would be where to insert the formatter html. thats the whole point of using the highlighter

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch for java FVH that claims to do this. I haven't personally tested it.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2464